# PDO and private class variables

Tags: php, pdo

Is it possible to submit data with PDO and having the class variables private instead of public?

I'd like to be able to use prepare and execute, in execute it's just array($classObject), but it has to have public variables.  Is there a way to use private variables and still use prepare and execute?

Example:

```
$query = $this->handle->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` ($fields) VALUES ($values)");
$query->execute(array($data));
```

Comment: Show us the code you are talking about and we can tell you.  If it is in the same class, then yes.  If outside, then no.

Comment: How PDO and access modifiers are related?

Comment: Updated the question a bit.  Basically, I prepare an insert statement and then execute with a class object.  If the variables are private, I get an HY093 error.

Comment: Guess your question is answered then, lol.  Create a function in the class that lets you return those private variables.  Or create another class extending the first with a function that returns those same variables.

Comment: Added some code to the question, but I really don't think having code there changes the question at all.  @TimWithers If I wrote access functions in the class, how does execute() use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to bind data to parameters in the query:

```
$value = 'Test';
$smt = $this->handle->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `$table` ('field1') VALUES (:value1)");
$smt->execute(array( ':value1' => $test ));
```

In the example I've used a single variable, but the example can be simple expanded to arrays, just by imploding them:

```
$data = array( 'field1' => 'Foo', 'field2' => 'Bar' );

$columns = implode( ", ", array_keys( $data ) );
$values  = ':' . implode( ", :", array_keys( $data ) );

$smt = $this->handle->prepare("
   INSERT INTO `$table` ($columns) VALUES ($values)");
$smt->execute($data);
```